# "Toy" human-language detection software

Tags: java, natural-language-processing, bloom-filter

I've written a small program to detect the human language of a document or text fragment.

I tried to stick to good design principles and I tried to make it pretty robust. I would be generously described as an intermediate programmer so I'm sure there are things that are bad-smellish that didn't even register with me.

The program works, but I wonder if there is any way to make it better. I always hear that software is never actually done, you just stop working on it.

Also, I'd like to know if you are about the download it from my [GitHub page](https://github.com/h1395010/i-Dentificateur/tree/e455e81dfcd3eeb1e0940e1a53870fc61bccb5db) and run it on your machine with no troubles, is it so?

The "load bearing" class which actually processes the input.

```
public class Processing 
{
    static double falsePositiveProbability = 0.1;
    static int expectedSize = 500000;

    //GERMAN
    static BloomFilter<String> de_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //ENGLISH
    static BloomFilter<String> eng_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //FRENCH
    static BloomFilter<String> fr_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //SPANISH
    static BloomFilter<String> es_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //ITALIAN
    static BloomFilter<String> it_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //PORTUGESE
    static BloomFilter<String> pt_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);
    //DUTCH
    static BloomFilter<String> nl_bloomFilter = new BloomFilter<String>(falsePositiveProbability, expectedSize);

    public static void process_input( List<String> input_text ) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
    {

        //THIS SEGMENT IS FOR DYNAMICALLY LOCATING THE DIRECTORY, SO THE PROGRAM WORKS "OUT OF THE BOX"
/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/
        //this holds all the dictionary files, i.e. word lists garners from language folders
        ArrayList<Path> dictionary_files = new ArrayList<Path>();

        File currentDir = new File(".");

        File targetDir = new File( currentDir, "ascii_word_lists" ); 
        //File targetDir = new File( currentDir, "unicode_word_lists" ); 

        if (targetDir.exists()) 
        {
            SearchDirectories.listDirectoryAndFiles( targetDir.toPath(), dictionary_files );
        }

/*******************************************************************************************************************************************/

        //this populates word presence data structs for each language
        for(Path dir : dictionary_files)
        {

            String word_holding_directory_path = dir.toString().toLowerCase();



            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream( dir.toString() ), "UTF-16LE") );

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( dir.toString() ) );
            String line = null;

            BloomFilter<String> bloomFilter;
            if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/de/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = de_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/eng/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = eng_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/fr/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = fr_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/es/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = es_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/it/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = it_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/nl/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = nl_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else if (word_holding_directory_path.toLowerCase().contains("/pt/")) 
            {
                bloomFilter = pt_bloomFilter;
            } 
            else 
            {
                continue;
            }

            while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ) 
            {
                bloomFilter.add( line.toLowerCase().trim() );
            }

        }


        Map<String, BloomFilter<String>> langMaps = new HashMap<>();
        langMaps.put( "Italiano, (Italian)", it_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "Français, (French)", fr_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "English, (English)", eng_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "Deutsch, (German)", de_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "Español, (Spanish)", es_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "Nederlandse, (Dutch)", nl_bloomFilter);
        langMaps.put( "Português, (Portugese)", pt_bloomFilter);


        int maxCount = 0;
        String maxLang = null;

        for (Map.Entry<String, BloomFilter<String>> entry : langMaps.entrySet()) 
        {
            int count = 0;
            BloomFilter<String> words = entry.getValue();

            for (String word : input_text) 
            {
                String normalized = word.trim().toLowerCase();
                if (words.contains(normalized)) 
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxCount) 
            {
                maxLang = entry.getKey();
                maxCount = count;
            }
        }

        //System.out.println( "Language is: " + maxLang );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Language is: " + maxLang);




    }
}
```

Locate the word lists

```
public class SearchDirectories 
{ 


    static void listDirectoryAndFiles( Path path , ArrayList<Path> dictionary_files ) throws IOException
    {

        DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream( path );
        for ( Path p : dirStream )
        {
            //System.out.println( p.getFileName() );
            if ( p.toFile().isDirectory() )
            {
                listDirectoryAndFiles( p, dictionary_files );
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary_files.add( p );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

User Interface

```
public class iDentificateur 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new iDentificateur();
    }

    public iDentificateur() 
    {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try 
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                UserInputPane userInputPane = new UserInputPane();
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, userInputPane, "Sentence", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        List<String> text = userInputPane.getText();
                        Processing.process_input( text );
                    } 
                    catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class UserInputPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField fldText;
        private JTextField fldFileName;
        private JButton browseFileButton;

        private File selectedFile;

        private JRadioButton rbText;
        private JRadioButton rbFile;

        public UserInputPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            rbText = new JRadioButton("Text: ");
            rbFile = new JRadioButton("File: ");
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(rbText);
            bg.add(rbFile);

            fldText = new JTextField(10);
            fldFileName = new JTextField(10);
            fldFileName.setEditable(false);
            browseFileButton = new JButton("...");

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(rbText, gbc);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(fldText, gbc);

            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(rbFile, gbc);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(fldFileName, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(browseFileButton, gbc);

            fldText.setEnabled(false);
            fldFileName.setEnabled(false);
            browseFileButton.setEnabled(false);

            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fldText.setEnabled(rbText.isSelected());
                    fldFileName.setEnabled(!rbText.isSelected());
                    browseFileButton.setEnabled(!rbText.isSelected());

                    if (rbText.isSelected()) {
                        fldText.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                }
            };

            rbFile.addActionListener(listener);
            rbText.addActionListener(listener);

            browseFileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

                    int returnValue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                        fldFileName.setText(selectedFile.getName());
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        public List<String> getText() throws IOException 
        {
            List<String> text = new ArrayList<>(25);
            if (rbText.isSelected()) 
            {
                //text.add(fldText.getText());
                for (String dialouge_word : fldText.getText().split("\\s+") )
                {
                    text.add( dialouge_word );
                }
            } 
            else if (selectedFile != null) 
            {

                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile))) 
                {
                    String value = null;
                    while ((value = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        //text.add(value);
                        for (String file_word : value.split("\\s+") )
                        {
                            text.add( file_word );
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return text;
        }

    }

}
```

Bloom Filter

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BloomFilter<E> implements Serializable 
{
    private BitSet bitset;
    private int bitSetSize;
    private double bitsPerElement;
    private int expectedNumberOfFilterElements; // expected (maximum) number of elements to be added
    private int numberOfAddedElements; // number of elements actually added to the Bloom filter
    private int k; // number of hash functions

    static final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); // encoding used for storing hash values as strings

    static final String hashName = "MD5"; // MD5 gives good enough accuracy in most circumstances. Change to SHA1 if it's needed
    static final MessageDigest digestFunction;
    static { // The digest method is reused between instances
        MessageDigest tmp;
        try 
        {
            tmp = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(hashName);
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) 
        {
            tmp = null;
        }
        digestFunction = tmp;
    }

    public BloomFilter(double c, int n, int k) 
    {

      this.expectedNumberOfFilterElements = n;
      this.k = k;
      this.bitsPerElement = c;
      this.bitSetSize = (int)Math.ceil(c * n);
      numberOfAddedElements = 0;
      this.bitset = new BitSet(bitSetSize);
    }


    public BloomFilter(int bitSetSize, int expectedNumberOElements) 
    {
        this(bitSetSize / (double)expectedNumberOElements,
             expectedNumberOElements,
             (int) Math.round((bitSetSize / (double)expectedNumberOElements) * Math.log(2.0)));
    }


    public BloomFilter(double falsePositiveProbability, int expectedNumberOfElements) 
    {
        this(Math.ceil(-(Math.log(falsePositiveProbability) / Math.log(2))) / Math.log(2), // c = k / ln(2)
             expectedNumberOfElements,
             (int)Math.ceil(-(Math.log(falsePositiveProbability) / Math.log(2)))); // k = ceil(-log_2(false prob.))
    }




    public static int createHash(String val, Charset charset) 
    {
        return createHash(val.getBytes(charset));
    }


    public static int createHash(String val) 
    {
        return createHash(val, charset);
    }


    public static int createHash(byte[] data) 
    {
        return createHashes(data, 1)[0];
    }


    public static int[] createHashes(byte[] data, int hashes) 
    {
        int[] result = new int[hashes];

        int k = 0;
        byte salt = 0;
        while (k < hashes) 
        {
            byte[] digest;
            synchronized (digestFunction) 
            {
                digestFunction.update(salt);
                salt++;
                digest = digestFunction.digest(data);                
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length/4 && k < hashes; i++) 
            {
                int h = 0;
                for (int j = (i*4); j < (i*4)+4; j++) 
                {
                    h <<= 8;
                    h |= ((int) digest[j]) & 0xFF;
                }
                result[k] = h;
                k++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        final BloomFilter<E> other = (BloomFilter<E>) obj;        
        if (this.expectedNumberOfFilterElements != other.expectedNumberOfFilterElements) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.k != other.k) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.bitSetSize != other.bitSetSize) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.bitset != other.bitset && (this.bitset == null || !this.bitset.equals(other.bitset))) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() 
    {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 61 * hash + (this.bitset != null ? this.bitset.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 61 * hash + this.expectedNumberOfFilterElements;
        hash = 61 * hash + this.bitSetSize;
        hash = 61 * hash + this.k;
        return hash;
    }




    public int getK() 
    {
        return k;
    }


    public void clear() 
    {
        bitset.clear();
        numberOfAddedElements = 0;
    }


    public void add(E element) 
    {
       add(element.toString().getBytes(charset));
    }


    public void add(byte[] bytes) 
    {
       int[] hashes = createHashes(bytes, k);
       for (int hash : hashes)
           bitset.set(Math.abs(hash % bitSetSize), true);
       numberOfAddedElements ++;
    }

    public boolean contains(E element) 
    {
        return contains(element.toString().getBytes(charset));
    }


    public boolean contains(byte[] bytes) 
    {
        int[] hashes = createHashes(bytes, k);
        for (int hash : hashes) 
        {
            if (!bitset.get(Math.abs(hash % bitSetSize))) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### When things go wrong...

If initialization of `MessageDigest digestFunction` fails,
you just assign it to `null`.
But the class will be unusable that way,
as when `createHashes` is called, that will lead to a null pointer exception.

Instead of a static initializer like this that might fail,
it would be better to create `MessageDigest` in the program's top-level function, and if such fundamental problems are detected than stop execution.

---

Similarly:

> ```
> try {
>     UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
> } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
>     ex.printStackTrace();
> }
>
> UserInputPane userInputPane = new UserInputPane();
> // ...
> ```

If `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` fails, you just print a stack trace and execution continues normally... It seems the program will be completely unusable like that.

As with the earlier problem, 
it would be better to handle this at a higher level in the program and exit if an unusable state is detected.

#### Naming

> ```
> private int k; // number of hash functions
> ```

Seriously? Even this would be better:

```
private int numberOfHashFunctions;
```

I would go with:

```
private int hashFunctionCount;
```

---

> ```
> public class iDentificateur
> ```

It would be better to use English consistently throughout the code,
and class names should be `PascalCase` in Java.

#### Placement of braces

This way of placing braces is not common in Java:

> ```
> public static int createHash(String val) 
> {
>     return createHash(val, charset);
> }
> ```

The way is to put the opening brace on the same line as the closing:

```
public static int createHash(String val) {
    return createHash(val, charset);
}
```

Your IDE can easily fix this for your entire code.

#### Update: more on placing braces...

The placement of braces is a convention, not a hard rule. You can do as you like. Just keep in mind that all the major IDEs today encourage this convention by the default behavior of their auto-reformat feature.

Neither brace placement style is better than the other.
But if you get used to the most commonly used style,
then if you have to review the work of other programmers,
you will likely see a familiar style,
and it will be easier to read.
If you prefer a different style than the most common,
then you will likely see a different style,
it will be harder to read, and you will be dismayed.

#### Update: more on detecting fundamental problems early

I pointed out above that your program doesn't handle well fundamental problems:
you print a stack trace, log, or null a variable, and let execution continue,
even though the program cannot possibly function well.
When problems critical to the basic functioning of the program are detected,
it might be tempting to just stop execution with `System.exit(1)`.

However, in your case,
the conditions are in fact pre-requisites,
not some random errors that can happen while the program is running.
As such, you could detect these problems in the `main` method that sets up your program elements and starts the execution of everything.
That would be the right place to check for preconditions (such as, can you can actually create a `MessageDigest` with "MD5"),
and exit otherwise.

Without catching missed pre-requisites early,
the problem crashes later, who knows when,
with a generic `NullPointerException` or something else that may not be very helpful for debugging the real cause of the malfunction.

Comment: I don't know why but I really detest the traditional java way of writing braces, it destroys my interal equilibrium, do you know what I mean? is it really so bad to write braces in the way I have?_____________________________________________________I don't know what you mean by handle the exceptions at a higher level.

Comment: I added 2 new sections at the end to explain these points in more detail.

Comment: @S.Matthew_English don't fret, these are just conventions after all. If you have used it consistently in projects which you have a say over conventions, so be it. :) You'll definitely blend in well with the C# crowd, though.

Comment: @h.j.k. that's why, because I first learned C# and C++ before I learned java, and I think that look more beautiful. i once read that people should write software to be readable by humans and only incidentally to compile, but anyway if i'm going to write software i want it to look beautiful to me!